# MouseBinding WheelClick not pass through

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using the following code in xaml to add a command to a mouse wheel scroll event. It is a item inside a itemscontrol. The command can be correctly triggered. However, the wheel scroll event seems not passed to its parent any more. So when I scroll the mouse wheel, the items inside the itemscontrol won't move anymore. How to solve this issue?

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="WheelClick" Command="{Binding MyMouseWheelCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```